# Unable to load ttf fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a CSS file that attempts to import `Open Sans`. I'm using `ttf` fonts downloaded from Google Fonts. I can't seem to get the font to work. It's still displaying the regular Times font.

**fonts.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    src: url("fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf") format("ttf");
}
```

**app.css**

```
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/fonts.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/app.css" />
```

My directory structure is like so:

```
/app
 - dist
   - fonts
   app.css
   app.js
   fonts.css
 index.html
```

I've used Chrome's inspector to check if the font file is being pulled in, but it isn't. There's also no error. If I include the `css` file directly from Google then it works. I also notice that Google serves a different font format that isn't `ttf`.

Note that I am developing a desktop application using Electron. Electron is powered by Chrome. My application is intended to run offline, hence why I am not linking directly to Google.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: protip: use the WOFF source, not `ttf`. But even more protip: just link straight to the google webfont. It lets browsers resolve that URL from cache, since a million other sites also use Open Sans from google webfonts.

Comment: Linking directly to Google isn't an option. I am creating an Electron desktop application which uses web technologies to build cross browser applications. The application is intended to run both online and offline and loading fonts from a URL when offline is impossible. Hence why I have to do it this way.

Comment: fair enough - stick with the WOFF anyway. Don't use the ttf or otf source. That said, there *is no* `format('ttf')`, that is not valid CSS syntax, so [have a look at the valid CSS font formats](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#descdef-src).

Answer (score 2):

The following worked:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  src: url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me. Using JavaScript to load the font

```
let openSans= new FontFace('Open Sans', 'url(./fonts/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFUZ0bbck.woff2)');
openSans.load().then(function(loaded_face) {
    document.fonts.add(loaded_face);
  document.body.style.fontFamily = '"Open Sans", Arial';
}).catch(function(error) {
    // error occurred
   console.error(error);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use google fonts you don't need to upload fonts files into your website folder, just add this url to your file html ( 

 )

and use font family in css : `font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;`

Comment: For Electron desktop applications you don't want to rely on pulling fonts directly from Google per request as applications are intended to have offline access.

Comment: Ok, I understand, so you can download font from google fonts and generate it to work in all browsers, for generate font you can use this website : https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: I don't need it to run in all browsers. Electron is powered by Chrome :p

Comment: i test in local, it's work, change format('ttf') to format('truetype')

Comment: Yes, this is the same as my own answer. I answered my own question a while ago. Thanks for your help though buddy. Much appreciated.